# Проблемы с proxy подключением

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

Может тут кто будет знать? Арендовал впс сервак. На компе приходится создавать подключение такого типа: `ssh -D localhost:9966 root@host`. Всё прекрасно работает с мобильным приложением Ki4a на телефоне, прописывая там ip и 9966 порт.Но как завернуть это всё в прокси на серваке? Вчера получилось, но, как я понял, UDP пакеты не проходят и в результате работает только браузер(80,443), а заблокированные вотсап, ютуб и т.п. не пашут. Именно в прокси хочется, т.к можно было бы прописать на ТВ, например, или просто в настройках телефона без заморочек с приложением.